CloudKit equivalent for Android
I’m wondering if there is something like CloudKit on iOS but with Google on Android.
I need a way to sync preferences in the cloud without having a user create an account. I’ve tried using anonymous accounts with firebase and supabase but I need a way for users to retrieve data from a new device.
